# How can I know what vendor subfolders were added by a composer dependency?

Tags: composer-php

I need to include "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0" in my Laravel project (on hosting server).
However, running "composer require" in console results in a PHP memory limit error.

It seems like I cannot change the memory_limit in php.ini

So, how do I know which vendor subfolders correspond to this package? So I can update it manually as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to copy your `composer.json` + `composer.lock` file from the server to your local machine, then run `composer install`, then run `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:^1.0` and copy the resulting `vendor` directory and `composer.json` + `composer.lock` back onto your server.

You could alternatively use git to determine what the differences are if you only wish to copy over the differences -- download your `vendor` directory + `composer.json` + `composer.lock` onto your local machine, create a new repository in that directory, commit: then run `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:^1.0` and perform `git diff`.

The reason for copying your `composer.lock` file is because that file maps dependencies to their specific versions, it's possible that if you just use `composer.json` you'll have some minor version differences which could cause breaking changes.